# How fix "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'"?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, attributeerror

I'm currently trying to do the "Hello Seaborn" tutorial from Kaggle. The first step is literally the stumbling block when trying to import all the necessary libraries.

They say to import the following libraries:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
print("Setup Complete")
```

which then produces the following error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 2
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'
```

So far from what I have been able to find to try and fix the problem online, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling 'plotting', updating pandas and updating matplotlib to their most recent versions as well as my anaconda distribution and python versions.

pandas-2.0.3
matplotlib-3.7.2
conda 23.5.0
python 3.10.9

I know Python 3.11 is out but it doesn't seem to let me update the python version through command prompt.

Comment: `import pandas; print(pandas.__file__)`. What does that print?

Comment: ~~\Documents\Python course\pandas.py
The name of a script I quickly named using pandas

Comment: ~~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py
Now that I deleted the file, this is the output

edit: and now it works! Thank you very much for your help, it's much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

found this [forum](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16536) on github

"Can you check if you have a (maybe empty) PyQt4 directory in your site-packages? Removing that should fix it."

Comment: There only a PyQt5 directory in my site-packages and not empty so don't know how important all the files in the directory are

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).